# Displaying Date 2 Days From Now Dynamically on Page

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to set up the Date +2 days from now a few times on my page.

So here is the code that I'm using:

```
<span class="spanDate"></span><br> at 8pm EST</div>
```

```
var dayName = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday','Saturday'];

var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July', 'August','September','October','November','December'];

var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setTime(tomorrow.getTime() + (1000*3600*48));

document.getElementsByClassName("spanDate").innerHTML = dayName[tomorrow.getDay()] + ", " + months[tomorrow.getMonth()] + " " + tomorrow.getDate()+ ", " + tomorrow.getFullYear();
</script>`
```

Questions:

1. why doesn't it work for me?
2. should I use `document.getElementsByID` instead? (I want to use the `span` multiple times on the page)

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("spanDate")` returns a collection of elements.

Comment: You can add dates with `tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 2)` which is easier to understand

Comment: I'll always favor learning over "just use this". Once you get the hang of these concepts, you might want to look into the - absolutely amazing - [date and time library Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: @SebastienDaniel, so how would I do the same thing with moment.js?

Comment: @Veit answered in an answer... it's cleaner to display :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to use Moment.js, you could "simplify" your code as follows:

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("spanDate")[0],
    tomorrow = moment().add(2, "d");

el.innerHTML = tomorrow.format("DD, MM, YYYY");
```

You'll notice that I added `[0]` after the `getElementsByClassName("spanDate")`, that's because the method `getElementsByClassName` returns an HTML collection (*array-like structure*). Once you have that collection, you need to extract the element that you want to modify (*in this case the first one we found [0]*).

Comment: The [Moment JS Docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/) are extensive and clear. A quick peek and you'll be on your way.

Comment: `.add(2, 'd')` is probably clearer based on the question title (I want to add 2 days), but both do the exact same thing. I'd always advocate using MomentJS for anything non-trivial with dates anyway, fantastic library.

Comment: Just wanted to keep it as close as possible to the OP. But yes, add(2, "d"); is "clearer".

Comment: just had to add `document.getElementsByClassName('spanDate')[0]` for each time I want to use it on the page.

Comment: That,s because `getElementsByClassNames` returns an HTML collection (i.e. array-like structure), so you need to get the collection element you want to operate on. In this case [0], gets the first one found, [1] would get the second, etc... One of the answers here explain that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35556421/3826468

Comment: @SebastienDaniel—they don't actually do the same thing. If one of the days is the day that daylight saving ends, it is 25 hours long (in most places that have DST), so adding 24 hours to 00:00:00 on that day only gets to 23:00, it doesn't change the date. So yes, it's far better to add 2 days to the date rather than 48 hours to the time.

Comment: I appreciate your insistence, Rob, but that issue was addressed by another poster, which I kindly referred to in the comments above. This post was an answer to an additional question asked later by OP.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
var dayName = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday','Saturday'];
var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July', 'August','September','October','November','December'];

var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setTime(tomorrow.getTime() + (1000*3600*48));
var dt = dayName[tomorrow.getDay()] + ", " + months[tomorrow.getMonth()] + " " + tomorrow.getDate()+ ", " + tomorrow.getFullYear();
//add [0]
document.getElementsByClassName('spanDate')[0].innerHTML = dt;
```

because this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("spanDate").innerHTML
```

returns a nodeList not an element.

**EDIT:**

If you have 5 span elements in your document where you want to show this date you can do it the classic way:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('spanDate')[0].innerHTML = dt;
document.getElementsByClassName('spanDate')[1].innerHTML = dt;
document.getElementsByClassName('spanDate')[2].innerHTML = dt;
document.getElementsByClassName('spanDate')[3].innerHTML = dt;
document.getElementsByClassName('spanDate')[4].innerHTML = dt;
```

or use a loop of any kind that will iterate through the nodes like this example:

```
var e = document.getElementsByClassName('spanDate');
for(i=0; i < e.length; i++) {
    e[i].innerHTML = dt;
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank You for the edit Aniket. It looks much better now :)

Comment: Note that adding 2 days of milliseconds doesn't necessarily increment the date by 2 days if one of those days is the day that daylight saving ends. Much better to add 2 to the date: `date.setDate(date.getDate() + 2)`.

Comment: Indeed @RobG, You are correct. The main problem was, how the questioner wanted to add the final result to the document. The results weren't showing at all so this was the focus of the problem. I left those calculations intact since the question hasn't been stated to check for errors elsewhere. Thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question: it is better not to use the same `id` multiple times in the same page.

Comment: 1 This is not an answer, 2 This is not related to the question

Comment: I war answering his second question: "shout I use document.getElementsByID instead? (I want to use the span multiple times on the page)"

Comment: @prtnkl actually did answer the 2nd part, so thanks!